# CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout for listview item single choice

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, store, android-custom-view

I am suing CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements Clickable for the row item of a list view single choice mode.

It is working fine about single choice. 
But when i close the app and open again my last selection do not show.
So, i want to store my selected position in shared preference, so that when i re-open the app i could show my selection.

How can i do that ??

CheckableRelativeLayout file code:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements
        Checkable {

    private boolean isChecked;
    private List<Checkable> checkableViews;

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialise(attrs);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialise(attrs);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, int checkableId) {
        super(context);
        initialise(null);
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#isChecked()
     */
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#setChecked(boolean)
     */
    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
        for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
            c.setChecked(isChecked);
        }
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#toggle()
     */
    public void toggle() {
        this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
        for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
            c.toggle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        final int childCount = this.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            findCheckableChildren(this.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the custom XML attributes
     */
    private void initialise(AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.isChecked = false;
        this.checkableViews = new ArrayList<Checkable>(5);
    }

    /**
     * Add to our checkable list all the children of the view that implement the
     * interface Checkable
     */
    private void findCheckableChildren(View v) {
        if (v instanceof Checkable) {
            this.checkableViews.add((Checkable) v);
        }

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            final int childCount = vg.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
                findCheckableChildren(vg.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML file for row item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.bashar.sample.CheckableRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_prayer"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/singleitemCheckBox"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_material_light"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text = "ListItem"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_name"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text = "Subtitle"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <com.bashar.sample.InertCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/singleitemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:button="@drawable/single_radio_chice" />

</com.bashar.sample.CheckableRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using `ListView` or `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0):

When you clicked list element change your model in adapter eg. `Boolean isChecked`. Use this field in adapter `getView(...)` method to set checked.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
           adapterInstance.changeChecked(position);     
            }
        });
```